# How to save JWT in Redis?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jwt

I'm creating a Spring Boot project with Java 8 and MongoDB. For session management I'm using a JWT token. I've searched many ways to invalidate the JWT token on logout. I read that it's possible to blacklist the token in Redis and validate towards it. How to store/save JWT in Redis? On Redis server restart saved JWT token data will be lost, right? How to handle it?

Comment: did you try anything to accomplish this so far ? You need to provide us some piece of code of what you tried to do, and tell us what doesn't work as intended. If you didn't try anything, I recommend that you look at the official redis documentation (https://redis.io/documentation), there is also a dedicated page about data persistence (https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to look more about docs. 
And I can tell you:

- you have many ways to store in redis
- redis support persistent data(But I don't suggest persistent data, you should use redis in cache not storage)